# Identifying Unique Values in Multi Select box

Tags: javascript, html, multi-select

I ran into a situation where I need your expertise to solve the problem.

I have three **multi select text boxes** namely `Roles`, `Database` and `RolesAssignedOnDatabase`.

Roles select box has values : `Read, Write, DBAdmin, UserAdmin`.
Database select box has values : `ABC,XYZ` etc..
**RolesAssignedOnDatabase select box is empty.**

Now user has to select a value from Roles selectbox and then from Database select box and finally click on Add button which will add a string pattern like `Roles@Database (for eg: read@ABC, read@XYZ)` in the third multi select box(RolesAssignedOnDatabase).

Now the trouble I am having is that if selecting the same values, uer clicks twice on add button then the third select box gets duplicate values like

```
 read@ABC,read@ABC,read@XYZ.
```

**How can I identify duplicate string values in multiselect box in javascript without looping to compare each value ?**

*(P.S I don't have enough reputation to paste the picture of the UI).*

Comment: You can put an external image link next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find()` of jQuery:

```
if($("#multi-select-wrapper").find(":contains('" + value + "')").length == 0) {
    ... // Add the element here.
}
```

Or if you prefer plain javascript you could use create the option values using this hack:

```
<option class="read@abc" value="read@abc">read@abc</option>
```

Then you can use:

```
var temp = document.getElementsByClassName(value)
if(temp.length == 0) {
    ... // Add the element here.
}
```

This is not recommended as class is not an a valid html attribute for option, though it will work for most browsers (hopefully): [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ge7Q2/1/)